# JAVA How do you iterate a 2d boolean array (synchronised with a generation counter or timer)?

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array, timer, while-loop

First of all, thank you for coming and taking the time to help with the problem.

I am a complete noob (3rd day programming) which explains why I have spent countless head-aching hours trying to solve this problem and still have not figured it out yet:

How do you iterate the grids (e.g. using for loop or while loop) so that the new grid replaces the old one and the newest grid becomes the new grid non-stop? I'm not familiar with the 'show()' method but I kind of got it to work.

Bonus Problem: How do you use the thread.sleep(1000) method so that the 2 grids pause one second or whatever before iterating? I think I should implement a generation counter as well so that the user can keep track of the growth.

Here's my incomplete code to give you an idea of the problem:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LifeGrid {



    public static boolean[][] gen() throws IOException {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("seed.txt"));
        int rows = 0, columns = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String s = scanner.nextLine();
            if (s.length() > columns) {
                columns = s.length();
            }
            rows++;
        }

        boolean[][] cells = new boolean[rows][columns + 1];
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(new File("seed.txt"));
        System.out.println("Original seed pattern:");
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            String line = scanner1.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            for (int c = 0; c <= line.length(); c++) {
                if (line.charAt(r) == '*') {
                    cells[r][c] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        return cells;
    }

    public static boolean[][] nextGen(boolean[][] cells) {
        boolean[][] newCells = new boolean[cells.length][cells[0].length];
        for (int r = 0; r < cells.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < cells[0].length; c++) {
                int num = numNeighbours(cells, r, c);
                if (occupiedNext(num, cells[r][c]))
                    newCells[r][c] = true;
            }
        }
        return newCells;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
        boolean[][] cells = gen();
        System.out.println("Generation:");
        show(cells);
        System.out.println("Next Generation:");
        cells = nextGen(cells);
        show(cells);
        System.out.println("Next Next Generation");
        cells = nextGen(cells);
        show(cells);
        System.out.println("Next Next Next Generation");
        cells = nextGen(cells);
        show(cells);
    }

    private static boolean inbounds(boolean[][] cells, int r, int c) {
        return r >= 0 && r < cells.length && c >= 0 && c < cells[0].length;
    }

    private static int numNeighbours(boolean[][] cells, int row, int col) {
        int num = cells[row][col] ? -1 : 0;
        for (int r = row - 1; r <= row + 1; r++)
            for (int c = col - 1; c <= col + 1; c++)
                if (inbounds(cells, r, c) && cells[r][c])
                    num++;
        return num;
    }

    public static void show(boolean[][] grid) {
        String s = "";
        for (boolean[] row : grid) {
            for (boolean val : row)
                if (val)
                    s += "*";
                else
                    s += "_";
            s += "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static boolean occupiedNext(int numNeighbours, boolean occupied) {
        if (occupied && (numNeighbours == 2 || numNeighbours == 3))
            return true;
        else if (!occupied && numNeighbours == 3)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate that you are new to this but you need to think about how you ask questions. 'How do you iterate the grids?' - What grids? It is not obvious from your code. It would be better if you explained exactly what your problem was.

Comment: Basically, I want to replace the old generation gen() with the new generation nextGen() with iteration continuously. How would I be able to do that?